# ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_COUNT - no such column summ_count

Tags: android, android-contacts

Trying to fetch contact groups on an Android 5.1.1. I was getting back duplicate groups so came across this answer ([Duplicate entries when fetching contacts groups Android 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282628/duplicate-entries-when-fetching-contacts-groups-android-4)).

While trying to implement the solution, I ran into a SQLite exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>
> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sum_count (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title FROM view_groups AS groups WHERE (1) AND ((deleted = 0 AND sum_count > 0)) GROUP BY groups._id ORDER BY title
>               at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)

Relevant code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

String[] projection = new String[]{Groups._ID, Groups.TITLE};
String selection = Groups.DELETED + " = 0 AND " + Groups.SUMMARY_COUNT + " > 0";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI, projection, selection, null, Groups.TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cursor groupCursor= getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI,
            new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,
                    ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_COUNT
            }, ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED+" = 0 AND "+ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_COUNT+">0", null, null
    );
```

The field has to be present in result set, then it works